# Four verbs meaning "to pursue": 追う, 追いかける, 追っかける and 辿る

Tags: word-choice, nuances, verbs

Consider the following four verbs:

- 追う【おう】 - *ou* ([view in jisho.org](http://jisho.org/word/%E8%BF%BD%E3%81%86))
- 追いかける【おいかける】 - *oikakeru* ([view in jisho.org](http://jisho.org/word/%E8%BF%BD%E3%81%84%E3%81%8B%E3%81%91%E3%82%8B))
- 追っかける【おっかける】 - *okkakeru* ([view in jisho.org](http://jisho.org/word/%E8%BF%BD%E3%81%A3%E3%81%8B%E3%81%91%E3%82%8B))
- 辿る【たどる】 - *tadoru* ([view in jisho.org](http://jisho.org/word/%E8%BE%BF%E3%82%8B))

**They all can mean "pursue". What are their differences?**

---

*Note: I did read their definitions and tried to catch some nuances by myself, but I am not sure about them. My thoughts was that the first three seem to carry an idea of a chase that requires effort, while the fourth allows an "easy" pursue, such as following a hyperlink on the internet. But even if this guess is correct, the difference between the first three verbs would remain unknown.*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

辿る is closer to "to trace (a road, a wire, etc)" and it does not mean "to chase". 追っかける is just a colloquial variation of 追いかける.

追う and 追いかける are *mostly* interchangeable. The primary meaning of 追う and 追いかける is "to chase (a car, a dream, etc)" or "to follow (an interesting topic, a person that has gone to another country, etc)". Perhaps the biggest difference is the level of formality. In casual conversations 追いかける is mainly used, while 追う sounds more formal and/or literary. In addition, only 追う means 追い立てる, "to drive (a herd of cattle, like a cowboy)".

**EDIT**: You may have seen [this post](http://webbinghaus.tumblr.com/post/119983281254/the-difference-between-%E8%BF%BD%E3%81%86-and-%E8%BF%BD%E3%81%84%E3%81%8B%E3%81%91%E3%82%8B), but I'm not really convinced by their explanation. In a drama, a senior police officer might say "(あの車を)追うぞ!" with great urgency and it sounds to me more formal and/or dignified than saying "追いかけるぞ!"

Comment: What's the difference between おいかける and おいかけまわす?

Comment: @Haragurodanshi That まわす adds the sense of "around" or "all over". See the 7th definition [here](https://jisho.org/word/%E5%9B%9E%E3%81%99).

Answer (score 3):

"追う" is the most general word and means "follow."

"追いかける" means "chase", not just "follow," but "follow and catch up."

"妻と喧嘩した。妻は家を出ていった。私はすぐに追いかけた。" "I had a quarrel with my wife, and she went out our house. I immediately chased my wife to catch up to her."

"追っかける" is rather casual. If you are a police officer, you should use the term "追いかける" not "追っかける." If you are a teenager, and chase your friend, you can use the term "追っかける."

"辿る":　Suppose there are several points, P1, P2, P3, P4, P5 in a sequential order. When you follow the points from P1 to P5 in order to get P5. Your behavior can be described as "辿る."

Answer (score 2):

追う and 追いかける - They have some difference nuances.
追いかける is **more urgent** than 追う. (So 追いかける can mean chase. )

---

辿る is not **urgent**. This can mean 'follow'.

---

追いかける and 追っかける - They are same, but 追いかける is more formal.

Comment: 「imperious」なんて、僕には聞いたことのない言葉です。「urgent」または比較級の「more urgent」のほうはどうでしょうか？

Comment: @oals 教えて下さり、ありがとうございました。直しときますね。